# When should someone use util.inherits() over prototypes in node.js for inheritance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

util.inherits(): Inherits methods from one function into another

Prototypes: Also offers inheritance.

So when should I use .inherits() and when should I change the prototype chain? 
Thanks.

Comment: `util.inherits` is nothing but a helper method *for* setting up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So when should I use .inherits() and when should I change the prototype chain?

`util.inherits()` uses the prototype so that assumption on your part is wrong.

It creates a new prototype object and copies over the properties from the previous prototype to make you a new prototype object that you can then add your own properties to.

What the node.js doc for `util.inherits()` recommends is that you use the ES6 `class` and `extends` syntax instead and `Object.create()` is also available.  `util.inherits()` is an old style way of doing things - it uses the prototype and it works, but is has been superceded by standard syntax.  I am not aware of any reason to continue to use it.

Comment: *“It creates a new prototype object and copies over the properties from the previous prototype to make you a new prototype object that you can then add your own properties to.”* The current implementation is `Object.setPrototypeOf`, IIRC.